# React JS Duplicate object within array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "rails" array within my `constructor` which are imported components:

```
import MusicRail from '../../components/MusicRail';
import GamesRail from '../../components/GamesRail';
import MoviesRail from '../../components/MoviesRail';

constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.rails = [
      MusicRail,
     GamesRail,
     MoviesRail
  ]
}
```

How can I clone or duplicate the first and last objects to then push to the `rails` array? Can I use `Object.assign()` ?

I'm getting the first and last objects from the array like so:

```
const rails = this.rails;
const firstObject = this.rails[0];
const lastObject = this.rails.slice(-1)[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` has nothing to do with `Array` (at least in this scenario), you may want to try this.

```
const rails = this.rails;
const firstObject = this.rails[0];
const lastObject = this.rails.slice(-1)[0];
this.rails = [...rails, firstObject, lastObject];
```

and if you're trying to build an infinite slider.

```
this.rails = [lastObject, ...rails, firstObject];
```

Comment: This is great! So my last question is, how can I push the clone of the first item to be last and then the clone of the last item be first? I'm trying to build an infinite slider.

Comment: @Littlee, Why not? Why `Object.assign` has nothing to do with `Array`?

Comment: Figured it out! Change the order of this.rails = [lastObject, ...rails, firstObject];

Comment: @Littlee Hey, I have a question - when I scroll to the last item which is a clone of the first in the array, I don't see the GamesRail after and so forth. You know like an infinite slider? Do you know how to go about this?

Comment: @Filth try this https://github.com/akiran/react-slick, if implementing it from scratch takes too much time. You may post another question, cuz answering in comment can't provide much details 

Answer (score 0):

Use myArray.slice() or lodash method _.cloneDeep()

You can also use concat or spread operator:

```js
let newArray = [
     ...arr
]
```